# Is there a utility to transpose a .csv file?

Tags: software-recommendation, libreoffice

I have some csv files with too many columns for LibreOffice Calc to open, but only a few rows. If I can transpose the csv file, it should be ok as Calc can deal with very many more rows than columns.

Comment: I doubt in what way does this *really* relate to Ubuntu. Just an honest doubt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple python program would do the job (and since this is not really tested: backup you csv file in advance!):

```python
import csv
import sys
infile = sys.argv[1]
outfile = sys.argv[2]

with open(infile) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    cols = []
    for row in reader:
        cols.append(row)

with open(outfile, 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for i in range(len(max(cols, key=len))):
        writer.writerow([(c[i] if i<len(c) else '') for c in cols])
```

You can save this into a file "my_csv_transposer.py" and call it from the commandline like this:

```
python my_csv_transposer.py <theinfilename> <theoutfilename>
```

Comment: nice, worked a treat, thanks (:  I used xrange rather than range to run a bit faster (minor point!).

Comment: nice script!  there is extra ')' at the end, otherwise awesome.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this script from the shell like this:

```
$ ./transpose_csv < theinfilename > theoutfilename
```

And here is the script:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, csv, itertools
rows = itertools.izip(*csv.reader(sys.stdin, delimiter=','))
sys.stdout.writelines(','.join(row) + '\n' for row in rows)
```

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/4869245/309483

Comment: for python3 with stdin/stdout i/o: `python3 -c "import sys,csv; csv.writer(sys.stdout).writerows(zip(*csv.reader(sys.stdin)))"`

Answer (score 1):

For reference's sake, here is the same incantation in Ruby:

```ruby
require 'CSV'

rows = CSV.new($stdin).read
puts rows.transpose.map { |x| x.join ',' }
```